# How to launch an LXD container on another node and exchange ssh keys with the container?

Tags: ansible, lxd

How to launch and LXD container on another node and exchange ssh keys with the container?
That is, how to give Ansible direct access to the LXD container using SSH?

I am aware of the authorized_key module however this would only exchange keys between the host and Ansible and not Ansible and the LXD container.

Please see the below diagram which describes the machine layout:

```
+----------------------------+        +----------------------------+
|                            |        |                            |
|     Baremetal Machine  <------------------+ Ansible Machine      |
|              +             |        |                            |
|              |             |        |                            |
|              |             |        |                            |
|              |             |        |                            |
|   +--------------------+   |        |                            |
|   |          |         |   |        |                            |
|   |          v         |   |        |                            |
|   |    LXD Container   |   |        |                            |
|   |                    |   |        |                            |
|   |                    |   |        |                            |
|   |                    |   |        |                            |
|   |                    |   |        |                            |
|   |                    |   |        |                            |
|   |                    |   |        |                            |
|   |                    |   |        |                            |
|   |                    |   |        |                            |
|   +--------------------+   |        |                            |
|                            |        |                            |
+----------------------------+        +----------------------------+
```

Comment: Haven't you asked the same question yesterday?

Comment: The question yesterday had negligible views so I reworded it to make it clearer. Although it may be difficult to perceive for a long time Ansible user, there is a rather large knowledge gap needed to go from bash scripts to Ansible Playbooks. With the continued move to containerization I am certain that this question will help many people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start containers from images that support some sort of provisioning system.
Most common is [cloud-init](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) – it's already inside many official cloud images.

When you create such a container, just add required configuration settings via `user.user-data` config option and it will be automatically applied when container started.

[lxd_container](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lxd_container_module.html) module support `config` parameter to set container [configuration options](https://github.com/lxc/lxd/blob/master/doc/containers.md).

You can find useful cloud config examples [here](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html#configure-instances-ssh-keys).

Comment: Given that cloud-init is only available on Ubuntu images from cloud-images.ubuntu.com, I'd like to know how you use it on other images from images.linuxcontainers.org. Thanks